# Clarification of a set description needed

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

S = {x in M | d(x,a) < d(x,b)} for any a,b in a metric space (I am not sure what this set is). Is S closed or open?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're not sure what the set is? You're told what the set is! $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary fixed elements of $M$ and $d$ is the metric.

Comment: In words, $S$ is the set of points of $M$ that are closer to the point $a$ than they are to the point $b$.

Comment: Right, so a is a cluster point, and S is open then?

Comment: If $M$ has the discrete metric, $a$ won’t be a cluster point! $S$ is open, but you have to do a little work to prove it. There are at least two fairly straightforward ways. One is to show that if $x\in M$, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(x,\epsilon)\subseteq M$. The other is to consider the function $f(x)=d(x,b)-d(x,a)$.

Comment: according to our notation it's actually <M,ro>, standard metric.

Comment: So we need to find disjoint open sets A and B that contain a and b? Like metric spaces with >1 element - Hausdorff in topology.

Comment: x∈M, B[x;min(b-x, x-a)] ⊆M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x\in S$, so that $d(x,a)<d(x,b)$. Show that for each $y\in M$

$$d(y,a)\le d(y,x)+d(x,a)\qquad\text{ and }\qquad d(y,b)\ge d(x,b)-d(x,y)\;.$$

Then show that if $d(x,y)<\epsilon$, then

$$d(y,b)-d(y,a)>d(x,b)-d(x,a)-2\epsilon\;.$$